# Hosting a php website in windows server 2008 with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, php, asp.net

I have an asp.net website hosted in IIS 7 in windows server 2008 which is running perfectly and is hosted on local server. I have only purchase the domain name without the hosting cuz the site is hosted locally & is access publicly over the internet. So, now i have created a php website which i want to host under apache and this is not working. The current asp.net site is accessible over https(port 443).

I have installed apache and tried hosting the php site under http (port 80), this site is not publicly accessed over internet. How can i make this php website to be accessible publicly? I have tried changing the ports but nothing seems to work! Really needed some help here. Thanks guys!

Comment: Why aren't you just using IIS and php?...

Comment: i've tried that

Comment: Sounds more like a firewall issue,  you can access localhost 80?

Comment: the site has access to localhost 80. i even changed the port to 81 so that it doesn't conflict with iis even though the asp.net site port is 443(https)

Comment: will the php site work if i disable iis?